# Best IRC Server & Services? (Debian)

Tags: linux, unix, irc

Using Debian (Lenny) here all update to date and such and I'm looking to setup an IRC server (I've done it before)

Just wondering whats the easiest to setup.  I'm looking for something thats also updated a lot and that has lots and lots of features :)

Thanks!

Comment: This is pretty vague, can you be more specific about your needs?

Comment: Just was looking for something easy to setup.  I've used Unreal IRCD and I think thats my only option with Anope services.

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I like InspIRCd which is easily modular and has API support.

http://wiki.inspircd.org/Comparison_Of_Features shows a comparison of features and a table of what services packages it supports.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty vague as said Meder but i would recommend [Unreal IRCD](http://www.unrealircd.com/).

EDIT: For the services i would consider using [Anope](http://www.anope.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Unreal IRCD became InspIRCd.

IRCServices eventually became Anope that then became: `atheme-services`. See bug numbers: [#424844](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=424844) [#646607](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=646607)

Hopefully by the time you read this I'll have some pkgs posted for atheme-services.

Comment: ...and The pkgs have been available for a while, in fact they have been updated at least once since I originally made them.

Comment: I tried both [Unreal IRCD](https://www.unrealircd.org/) and [InspIRCd](https://www.inspircd.org/). They are very much two distinct products. Yes, first plugin evolved: **IRCservices (achurch version)** -> **epone** -> **[Anope](https://github.com/anope/anope)**, but [Atheme](https://atheme.github.io/atheme.html) is a separate plugin. Anope has 70.5% usage share while Athene 13.9% (2019)

Answer (score -1):

We've been pretty happy with `ircd-hybrid` server and the `hybserv` services collection; it's relatively widely used and has some useful modules. It's also still under active development.

http://www.ircd-hybrid.org/